# Responsive table using CSS display: table-row

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I'm having trouble converting my table to a more responsive design, I've tried many resources on Google but they are all limited and do not work like intended. The underlying problem I'm having is that my tables are dynamically generated and I do not want to edit resources I find on Google so I can update them easily and don't mess with the code too much.

Anyway, my table has a really simple design. There are 5 columns with X rows (depending on what's being generated from the database). Whenever an user resizes their browser (or when they are using a mobile phone) I want to change my table so it is fitting on smaller screens as well. An example of this would be:

**Desktop**

```
Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3
------------------------------
Content  | Content  | Content
```

**Phone**

```
Header 1 | Content
------------------
Header 2 | Content
------------------
Header 3 | Content
```

I'm trying to accomplish this by using `display: table-row` using CSS whenever the screen hits a certain width, I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtfLgrga/1/) to display my current code. However currently the `th` and `td` are displayed vertically above/under each other, and not next to each other like I intended to do. I tried using `float: left` and `float: right` but that does not work (see the jsfiddle). Can anybody help me accomplish what I want using CSS? And if that is not possible, how would I go over using Javascript for this, keeping in mind that my tables will not all be generated when the page is loaded (some are dynamically added to the page)?

Comment: Have a look at the container css class from bootstrap. This will lead you to somewhere.

Comment: Here's a nice article about responsive tables from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens I am failing to see what `margin` and `padding` would be helpful for in this case, which is what what `container` class from Bootstrap has.

Comment: @Vucko I've read that one already, but they are giving solutions that I don't want to implement because they do not provide solutions I need (a pie chart, for example), and the only solution that comes close to my case does not work for me, as my tables are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `thead` and `tbody` elements, you could try like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/uzsw7s4o/

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    tbody, thead { float: left; }
    thead { min-width: 120px }
    td,th { display: block }
}
```

Comment: looks promising, but is there a way to prevent the table to be fully vertically if you resize the browser to under 100px? Currently it works in a certain range, but still collapse to what I have in my example.

Comment: you could add a min-width to the table element or set a relative width to the `thead` and `tbody` (e.g. 50% each)

Comment: Hey there again! I implemented your solution and I was wondering if it is also possible to have a `thead` for all `td` elements, because we sometimes have more then 1 row. I know that it isn't possible with `thead` itself, but maybe with captions? Or what would the best way be?

Comment: not sure about your goal, but you may have many tbody elements in the same table

Answer (score 5):

How about adjusting the `table` definitions for the different screen widths. This also prevents any unanticipated side effects of floating your elements.

### [Resizable Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtfLgrga/2/)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .cell {
    display: block;
  }
  .row {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Head #1</div>
    <div class="cell">Head #2</div>
    <div class="cell">Head #3</div>
    <div class="cell">Head #4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Content #1</div>
    <div class="cell">Content #2</div>
    <div class="cell">Content #3</div>
    <div class="cell">Content #4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have forked you fiddle. That is the way I would solve it:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <span>Head #1</span>
    <span>Head #2</span>
    <span>Head #3</span>
    <span>Head #4</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span>Content #1</span>
    <span>Content #2</span>
    <span>Content #3</span>
    <span>Content #4</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row
{
    display: table-row;
}
.row > *
{
    display: table-cell;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .row
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    .row > *
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, based on your answer to this question, any chance you have a better answer for another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801114/responsive-table-with-repeating-column-groups